# Generating sequential numbering for duplicate values in a field sorted by ObjectID

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am trying to figure out a solution to an field calculation problem. What I'm trying to do is automatically (using either ArcPy or the Field Calculator) generate sequential numbers, beginning at 1, in a new blank integer field (called 'Point_ID') for every recurrence of a value in a second field (called 'Line_ID'). The sorting of the sequential values in the second field ('Line_ID') will be based on the order in a third field ('FID'). Can anyone help me do this? I am very green when it comes to advanced field calculations and ArcPy (and Python in general, for that matter). So your explicitness is much appreciated.

Another way to put it: there are duplicate values in the Line_ID field. I would like to create a new field that counts up for every duplicate occurrence in the Line_ID field, with the sort order based on the FID field. So, if there are nine values in the Line_ID field that have the value "A," the new Point_ID field will go from 1 to 9, with the order based on the sort on FID.

Comment: I think ArcPy and the Field Calculator are both overkill for this.  I would try using the [**Summary Statistics**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool with a case_field of Line_ID first and if that does not give you a solution then perhaps add a picture of the input and expected output for your process to your question using the edit button.  I'll +1 your question in case you have insufficient reputation to do that.

Comment: I had this same problem and had trouble working out the right python snippet to sue in the field calculator. Jason Miller's response works a treat!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144211)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how green you are, so here are "pretty explicit" instructions...

1. Open up Field Calculator on the Point_ID field
2. At the top, choose the "Python" parser
3. Click the checkbox beside "Show Codeblock"
4. In the "Pre-Logic script code", paste the following code...

   ```
   prevFieldValue = ''
   counter = 1
   def GetDuplicateCounter(myFieldValue):
     global prevFieldValue
     global counter
     if myFieldValue == prevFieldValue:
       counter += 1
     else:
       counter = 1
     prevFieldValue = myFieldValue
     return counter
   ```
5. In the "Point_ID = " box, type in   `GetDuplicateCounter(!Line_ID!)`

Note: If your Line_ID field is not a string field, then change the first line of code to `prevFieldValue = 0` or something similar...

Comment: This worked like a charm. I'm only green when it comes to the syntax of the code itself; I understand the logic and how to use the field calculator. But thanks a lot for a perfect solution and for being extra explicit! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The order of my Line_ID was random (compared to FID). Just an extra step of sorting the table and it worked great.