# How to remove repetitive text in attributes?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I would like to clean up fields that contain repeated "Street Names". As seen below, I have fields "Name_From" and "Name_To". These fields sometimes repeat the same name (highlighted). I would like to remove these repeated street names.

As seen below in the Name_From field, the highlighted record says "Preller & Preller". I would like to end with only "Preller". ("Preller & Preller" becomes only "Preller".)

This repetition is also present in the Name_To field.

.[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate records in field using ArcGIS for Desktop?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82921/finding-duplicate-records-in-field-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

Comment: @Dean van den Heever, I don't see how it is a duplicate. The first row is from: Preller&Preller and to: President&President; the second is from: Steyn&Steyn and to: Preller&Preller. Is it a duplicate since Preller&Preller shows both on from and to in different rows which makes no sense at all? or is Preller&Preller, etc. the duplicate, and you would like it to be: Preller instead..?

Comment: Yes. The Preller & Preller is the duplicate. I would like to be only left with one Preller text. This duplication of records are present in both the Name_from and Name_to fields respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If your values always have a charater between two street names (e.g. "&"), you may use this python function in field calculator:

```
def updateField(field):
  found = field.find('&')
  if found > -1:
    firstStreetName = field.split(' ')[0]
    secondStreetName = field.split(' ')[2]
    if firstStreetName.upper() != secondStreetName.upper():
      return field
    else: return firstStreetName
  else: return field
```

**updateField(!myField!)**

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the job. You should run it separately for each field.
Use python in field calculator, and paste this into your Code Block:

```
def Dupli(field, char="&"):
  charLoc = field.find(char)
  strLeft = field[:charLoc].strip()
  strRight = field[charLoc+1:].strip()
  if (strLeft == strRight):
    return(strRight)
  else:
    return(field)
```

and paste this as your field calculator value

```
Dupli('same field name',"&")
```

Notice that you should use the same field name, i.e. if you try to remov duplicates from the 'FROM_NAME' field, and the separator that is used to separate names is '&', your code will look as follows:

```
 Dupli(!FROM_NAME!,"&")
```