# Generating composite values ( MAPFID numbers) for previously duplicated vales based on 2 different fields

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes, file-geodatabase

I am attempting to edit a file GDB that contains over 1.5 million forest stand polygon records and change those that have a specific duplicated value.  I will most likely be obtaining the information on how to do that from [Generating sequential numbering for duplicate values in a field sorted by ObjectID](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67916/generating-sequential-numbering-for-duplicate-values-in-a-field-sorted-by-object), and since the data is stored on a file GDB, I will also be sourcing some code from [Python script for identifying duplicate records (follow up)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70994/python-script-for-identifying-duplicate-records-follow-up), however that is the part that I have mostly figured out already.

My problem right now is that I am not familiar enough with python terminology to even properly *explain* the next step so I am going show you my thought process on this as best as I can. Warning: this explanation is not going to be in proper syntax simply because I am not very good at writing it quickly yet.

This is the part I think I understand what to do

IF Field A(called'NP')>0 AND Field B(called 'PREFID')contains a duplicate value THEN generate unique 'PREFID' value counting from +9999

and this is where it goes astray for me:

Where a new value is created based on this criteria, I need another existing field (called 'MAPFID') to have a new value generated that will be a composite of the values in that row for the fields 'MAP' and the newly created 'PREFID' number. This field is called 'MAPFID'.  Eg: if MAP=1343590 and PREFID=10000 then the value in MAPFID=134359010000

Because the 'MAP' value is based on UTM coordinates, the values for 'MAP' will not necessarily be sequential.