# assign a number for each group in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I have several thousand features each of which has a name. The names are not unique.
what I want to do with the field calculator is assign a number to each name so I can refer to a number and always get the same name.

For example if I had:

```
chris, dave, chris, tom, dave, chris , dave, tom
```

I'd like my number column to show

```
1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3
```

Is this something I can do using python in field calucator?

Comment: Is your list always going to be table dependent (each table/layer may have a slightly different list)?

Comment: this option is very interesting. Can we us the "Codeblock" if- elif calculation in a stand alone arcpy script ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/83603)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/83603)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* you know all of the possible input values in advance, it is possible to do this with Field Calculator by turning on the "Codeblock" and creating a function like the following:

```
def classify(name):
  if name == 'chris':
    return 1
  elif name == 'dave':
    return 2
  elif name == 'tom':
    return 3
  else:
    return 0
```

And then the expression you would use to calculate another numeric field using that function would be:

```
classify(!NAME_FIELD!)
```

If you *don't* know all of the possible values in advance, or if there are so many that it would be ridiculous to type an `elif` statement for each one, you'd probably have to write a custom Python script to do this for you instead of using Field Calculator.

---

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, if you don't care about the specific numeric value assigned to each unique text value, this can probably be done with a global list variable in the codeblock, with the following code (based on your comment):

```
mylist = []
def classifier(value):
    global mylist
    if value not in mylist:
        mylist.append(value)
    return mylist.index(value)
```

Comment: `calculate(!NAME_FIELD!)` or `classify(!NAME_FIELD!)`?

Comment: My mistake; haven't had enough coffee yet...

Comment: thanks, I don't have the list of names so it looks like I'll need a separate script.
Do you think I could do it in the codeblock with by adding each name to a list then if the next name features in the list getting the index position?

Comment: It may work if you create a global variable, similar to the code in this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67916/generating-sequential-numbering-for-duplicate-values-in-a-field-sorted-by-object/67941#67941

Comment: Am I barking up the wrong tree with this then?
mylist = []
def classifier(value):
 if value in mylist:
  mylist.append(value)
  return mylist.index(value)
 else:
  mylist.append(value)
  return mylist.index(value)

Comment: Barking up the *right* tree. I've edited my answer with a modified version of that code, which I think should work for you.

Comment: It worked. you are a genius! thank you.
Now I need to go away and read about global variables

Answer (score 1):

What about looping through, throwing the names in a dictionary as keys? Use a counter to add the value if the key doesn't exist, otherwise use the value from the key. So 'Chris' doesn't exist when first encountered; 'Chris' becomes the key and 1 the value. Then 'Dave is next, doesn't exist, so becomes a new key with 2 as the value. Then 'Chris' is encountered again, but Chris already exists as a key, so that value, 1, is used, and so on.