# Create sequential numbers based on field value using Python in the Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.4, python-parser

I'm trying to modify the `autoIncrement()` python script to auto number based on another field. For example, I need the autoincrement to restart when the field "STD_ID" changes value. This is my attempt but I'm not getting the results I need.

```
rec=0
stand = "STD_ID"
stand2 = "STD_ID"
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    global stand
    global stand2
    pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
    pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
    stand2 = "STD_ID"
    if (rec == 0): 
        rec = pStart 
    elif (stand2 == stand): 
        rec = rec + pInterval  
    else:
        rec = 1
        stand = "STD_ID"  
    return rec
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Which GIS software are you using?  Please [edit] your question to include this info.

Comment: "I'm not getting the results I need" - What are the results you are getting, and how do they differ from what you need?

Comment: Your `else` will never be hit, as `elif stand2 == stand` will always be true (as far as I can tell).  the values for these two parameters never change from `STD_ID`

Comment: So you want each instance of 'std_id' to get a unique contiguous value.. is that correct? How are you calling this? Is it in a python script or field calculator?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson says Field Calculator in the question title...

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Comment: Within ArcGIS 10.4.1, I'm attempting to use Field Calculator w/ Python expression type. You are correct that the elif stand2 == stand is always true. Therefore, the return value is 1 through 10 for example. What is the proper method in setting the second variable "stand2" to store the current records "STD_ID" value as it moves through each table row? I would like to have 1 for STD_ID = 1; next row 2 for STD_ID = 1; next row 1 for STD_ID = 2 etc...

Comment: @Jeff Please **[edit]** your question to include additional information or clarification.

Comment: Field 1 = STD_ID

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. I did not initially find the answer that I was looking for. The answer was found at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67916/generating-sequential-numbering-for-duplicate-values-in-a-field-sorted-by-object?rq=1